# Pointers for dealing with instability in fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, simulations, stability

I have been working on a 2D fluid simulator, and I have fallen victim to the problem of jumping in before doing enough research. I naively implemented a finite difference form of the continuity and Navier-Stokes equations with an RK4 integrator, and upon troubleshooting discovered that I was quickly running into what I assume to be numerical instability.

Here's a couple screenshots of what happens when I add a circular source of density to a low density background, and let it spread out for a few seconds, along with a slight flow to the right:

[image: Spreading seemingly normally]

Spreading seemingly normally

[image: Instabilities become visible]

Instabilities become visible

[image: Instabilities break into a hole, in this case with one high density point]

Instabilities break into a hole, in this case with one high density point

[image: Hole expands very quickly to cover the screen]

Hole expands very quickly to cover the screen

Could anyone direct me towards material to help me understand, and hopefully mitigate these instabilities? Have I gone about this project in a completely untenable direction? Are there any "quick fixes"?

Thanks for any guidance!

Comment: Are you clamping the density to be non-negative?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of the finite difference scheme you are using?

Comment: Perhaps a candidate for the [scicomp.SE] forum.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I wasn't aware that StackExchange existed!